# Is there a way to do comparative updates and fire a lambda function if an update is a success?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want an AWS Lambda function to poll a remote API then push the data to DynamoDB table every X minutes.

I was wondering if there's a way to ask DynamoDB to check for changes and then fire a Lambda function if a specific value has been modified?

```
 'id': 1,
 'photo': 'photo.jpg',
 'name': 'Steve',
 'team': 'blue',

 'id': 1,
 'photo': 'photo.jpg',
 'name': 'Steve',
 'team': 'green',
```

Result: team value changed blue>green therefore execute function called changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely do this with DynamoDB by creating a trigger with the New and Old Images stream type, but DynamoDB will not check the record for you. It will just send you the records that have been updated whether new, old or both. It's possible that you have a record that has the same fields. That wouldn't be ideal.. so you'd want to code defensively on what gets put into the table making sure nothing is using put_item that overwrites the record with the same data. Below is a sample event (focus on new and old image, event ID and versions and such are just mock data).

````
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventID": "2",
      "eventVersion": "1.0",
      "dynamodb": {
        "OldImage": {
          "id": {
            "N": "1"
          },
          "name": {
            "S": "Steve"
          },
          "photo": {
            "S": "photo.jpg"
          },
          "team": {
            "S": "blue"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "222",
        "Keys": {
          "id": {
            "N": "1"
          }
        },
        "SizeBytes": 59,
        "NewImage": {
          "id": {
            "N": "1"
          },
          "name": {
            "S": "Steve"
          },
          "photo": {
            "S": "photo.jpg"
          },
          "team": {
            "S": "green"
          }
        },
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "awsRegion": "eu-west-1",
      "eventName": "MODIFY",
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:account-id:table/ExampleTableWithStream/stream/2015-06-27T00:48:05.899",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb"
    }
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can [Capture Table Activity with DynamoDB Streams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) and trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever there is an update to a given DynamoDB table.

You might not be able to trigger it *only* on a 'change', but the Lambda function could add some logic to only react to a changed value (as opposed to a new value or a deleted value).